# how to make sure Data is replicated across all the replicas in SolrCloud?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr6

previously i was using Master slave configuration, in which i was querying every slave after indexing it to make sure my changes are reflected on every Slave.
 first i was requesting with

```
SlaveSolrURL/replication?command=fetchindex and checking if status is OK
```

then
i was querying following in a loop

```
SlaveSolrURL/q=QueryForMyChange and breaking my loop when i get expected result
```

and then enabling Slave for Querying.

How can i do this functionality in SolrCloud, to make sure my changes are replicated across every replica, i am using single Shard only.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your changes to any solr instance and solrcloud will automatically share the updates to all nodes.

Comment: But when my changes are in the process of replication, at that time a query fired for that change then my replica will not have it, since solrcloud does indexing asynchronously.

Comment: I believe that the commit does not take effect until all of the nodes are updated